# Screen size for android app

Tags: android

i am developing an android application targeting only phones( not tablets). i want to know that how may type of layout do i have to define out of the four layout- small, large, normal, x-large. i saw in android studio that whenever i switch my app layout to large the nexus 7 device comes up. so do i have to make large layout for my application although it is a tablet.

and how to define that my application is only for phones. i have written this in my manifest file. what else do i have to do?

```
<compatible-screens>

        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 3):

Different layouts for different screen sizes and densities are not required.  Android will use just one default layout but it will choose the best when there are multiple: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html  Layout selection can allow for things such as separate portrait and landscape layouts and also behavior changes (see Master/Detail Flow template Activity in Android Studio).

You can limit what devices can use your app via the manifest but you should just allow everything unless you really need to.  Other devices will just scale the default layout.  If you must filter in the Play Store, you should use the Supports Screen element instead of Compatible Screens:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html  You can also do some filtering in the Play Store but I've never used that.

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** limit your app usage unless you **really** need to (you usually do not). If you want, you can check if you are running on tablet and show dialog saying "*Hey, glad you choose our app. Sorry it sucks on tablet yet, but we do our best. Stay tuned for the update!*". Do not artificially block users from using it if they need to, especially for no real reason. That sucks even more than lack of direct tablet support.

Answer (score 0):

An android application can run on any android device that has the appropriate version of the android operating system.  You CAN limit what devices are supported when you submit your application to the google play store.  In this way you can limit it to phones and specific devices.

Comment: actually in terms of UI i was wondering. so i dont have to make extra layouts for large and xlarge??

Comment: @Nick provided a better answer along the same lines.